# How to find the minimum in an array, excluding the first index

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic4

I have an array that has a value of 0. Whenever the user inputs a number which is tied to a deposit variable, the customerAccount variable becomes updated, that customerAccount variable is then pushed to the first index of the array. I want to now check if the customer balance is less than all the values in the array, except the first index.

I have tried the following below:

```
deposit: number;
withdrawal: number;
customerAccount=0;
previousBalance=[0];


calculateDeposits(){

// User inputs amount and the deposit updates the currentAccount 
this.customerAccount += this.deposit;

// The customer Account is then placed to the first index of the array 
this.previousBalance.unshift(this.customerAccount);


// This is where it goes wrong:

if (this.customerAccount >= Math.min(...this.previousBalanceArray)) {

// Run Some Code
        }


}
```

I only want the minimum value of all the items in the previousBalance array except the first index, however all I am getting the minimum of the entire array.

Comment: You could, of course, do the check before modifying the array.  But that's not what you asked.

Answer (score 3):

You could slice the array with [`Array#slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) and get all items without the first one.

```
Math.min(...this.previousBalanceArray.slice(1))
```